# Modifying AWS EC2 windows firewall settings

Tags: ftp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp-client, windows-firewall

I am trying to execute a FTP script on windows AWS EC2 instance to download a file , but the inbound connection is being blocked due to firewall settings. Can anybody suggest what should be the appropriate firewall configuration that it should have to allow inbound connections.

I am afraid to play around with these settings because I once clicked on reset firewall settings and the I lost the remote login access for that instance and I had to terminate it and create a new one.

Thank you.

```
@echo off
echo user  username > ftpcmd.dat
echo password >> ftpcmd.dat
echo binary >>ftpcmd.dat
echo cd /Outbound/Archive >>ftpcmd.dat
echo prompt n >>ftpcmd.dat
echo get DATA_FEED.xml C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test.xml >> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.server.com
del ftpcmd.dat
```

[image: Below is a screen shot of Ec2 firewall settings]

Comment: If you want to download a file from one server to your EC2 instance you should be able to do this without any firewall changes. Are you in a VPC network or default EC2?

Comment: I am using a default EC2. When I run the FTP script , I am able to login , but when the execution comes to "get" it hangs for some time and command prompt closes.

Comment: Could you add this script to your question?

Comment: I added the script to my question. The same script ran successfully on my pc.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple solution:**

Try to add

```
echo quote pasv >> ftpcmd.dat
```

just before sending `binary`.

**Explanation:**

`PASV` sets the connection to [passive mode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2428), which does not need any incoming connection from the server. This just works like a simple client-server connection.

In active mode, the client connects to the server (which works in your case, login success), then tells the server it's own IP address and a random port, typically above 1023.
The server then connects to your client to transfer the data.
This fails because you are behind a firewall.

Comment: No luck same problem. Please look at this http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/configure-ftp-exe-use-passive-mode-pasv-t3655119.html

Comment: Ok, got you. If you can't use another client which supports passive mode you need to allow ports above 50000 inbound at your firewall and your ec2 security group

Comment: Actually I turned off the firewall completely ..even then I get the same error - connection closed by remote host. And in the security group I included TCP 0-65535 ports open. even then no luck.

Answer (score 1):

AWS documentation has -

The File Transfer Protocol (FTP) has a PORT command by which a client sends its address back to the server. The server then connects to the client at that address to send the file data. If the client looks up its own internal address and sends this to the server, the connection will fail. In this specific case, there are two solutions to the problem. First, configure the client to send its public IP address. Second, the client can use "passive FTP" which makes connections only to the server, rather than from the server to the client. In general, applications which encode local addresses and port numbers in data sent to external servers might have problems with NAT. Care must always be taken to send the public address, rather than the internal one. 
We recommend using passive mode unless it is not supported by the FTP server.

I didn't try to expose public IP of my AWS instance and we know the FTP.EXE doesn't support passive mode , so I used NcFTP and I was able to download the file.